# Error trying to create an instance of GoogleIdTokenVerifier using the Java Google Client Api

Tags: java, google-api, google-signin, google-api-java-client, google-client

i'm trying to integrate the google login function on my website and i'm following the relative google doc for the  server side token validation: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token?hl=en .

i've created a simple test app with the GoogleIdTokenVerifier declaration but i'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

this is the test app with the GoogleIdTokenVerifier declaration:

```
package test;

import java.util.Collections;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
            HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
            
            GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, new GsonFactory())
                // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"))
                // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
                //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
                .build();

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the pom.xml i used for the dependencies:

```
    <project>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.3</version>
   </dependency>
   
  </dependencies>

  
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample for this on the [Verify the Google ID token on your server side](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) documentation page

You apear to be using an old sample i dont think they use `GsonFactory` anymore with the java library it was removed.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;

...

GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
    .build();

// (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)

GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
if (idToken != null) {
  Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

  // Print user identifier
  String userId = payload.getSubject();
  System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

  // Get profile information from payload
  String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

  // Use or store profile information
  // ...

} else {
  System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
}
```

Comment: this sample from doc does not helpful. What should be then 'transport, jsonFactory' ? It was question of the author, we are on the same stage in integration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple sample of usage:

```
  @Slf4j
  @Service
  @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  class SocialAuthGoogleValidator implements SocialAuthValidatorStrategy {

    @Override
    public void validate(LoginSocialInput input) {
      log.debug("Validate: {}", input);

      NetHttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

      GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory)
        .setAudience(Arrays.asList(
          "your-client-id",
          "your-client-id-2"
        ))
        .build();

      try {
        GoogleIdToken googleIdToken = verifier.verify(input.getProviderIdToken());
        log.debug("Google ID token: {}", googleIdToken);
        //todo here do wanted validation

      } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        log.warn("Token issue: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Invalid Google Auth");
      }
    }
  }
```